# unrecognized selector on NSArray : 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I am sitting since a hour on some strange exception. 
I try to call some method with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
            NSLog(@"selected Element: %@", [[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i]);
            [self addElementsToView:dash withString:[[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i] index:index andSubindex:i];
        }
```

the method is of types: - `(void) addElementsToView: (UIView *) dash withString: (NSString *) type index:(NSInteger)index andSubindex : (int) i {}`

`NSLog` shows me:

> selected Element: NUMBER
>   so the index stuff is ok. 
>   Why I get on the next step the following exception:
>
> [__NSArrayI intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x14d44f70  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI intValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d44f70'

**UPDATE:**  The DBElements is:

> (
>           (
>           NUMBER,
>           LABEL
>       ),
>       LABEL
>   )

index is 0 
i is 0. so it shows to NUMBERS of type NSString.

Comment: Split up all objectAtIndex operations into different lines, enable exception breakpoint and see where it happens exactly. It's hard to predict what you have in those arrays - maybe give a dump of data you are iterating through

Comment: Your DBElements must contain objects which are not NSArray

Comment: Please share the code of addElementsToView too. Also pls set a breakpoint on this method - as I understand it gives the exception trying to execute this method, is it so?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the Method. I get this exception by trying to call it. It's in the next line after NSLog.

Comment: Please show all your code, including addElementsToView method, how you initiate DBElements and dash.

Comment: So you put a breakpoint into the addElementsToView and before it captured an exception happened: with this few code information I would try to cast "withString:[[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i]" like this: "withString:(NSString *)[[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i]"

Comment: @codedad : Yeah, you are right. It works now. Please write the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast

```
withString:[[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i]
```

like this:

```
withString:(NSString *)[[DBElements objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:i]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code **you are calling** `intValue` **on a** `NSArray`. Maybe in the `addElementsToView` method.

Looking at the (short) code sample I assume it has something to do with DBElements. You probably want to call intValue on a NSString to convert it to number value.

If you have an Arrays nested in Arrays then make sure you're calling the right selectors on the right objects.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.  In fact it looks like a summary of the existing comments.

Comment: answer: 'you are calling intValue on an NSArray'

Comment: Now you are summarising the exception message.

Comment: So the exception message can not be part of the answer? Let's not waste our time and wait for Watsche to see if it brought him on the right track.